# How do i change the class of container to container-fluid when change the uiview using angular ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am a Starter in angularjs. Having 5 more pages controlled over uiview to get the pages.
I need to change the style from container to container-fluid where i used uiview in index page.

In html,

```
<div class="container" ui-view> </div>
```

For only one page i need to change the class to container-fluid.

I tried like this.

In html,

```
<div ng-class="{container-fluid: clearance}" ui-view> </div>
```

In controller i mentioned,

```
$scope.clearance= true;
```

It does not renders the ngclass. Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

An object property name can't have a `-` in it without quoting that whole name

Try

```
<div ng-class="{'container-fluid': clearance}" ui-view> </div>
```

Also depends which controller you are referring to. If it is the controller referenced in the routing config, then it will only have scope inside the `ui-view`

Comment: <div ng-class="{'container-fluid': 'clearance'}" ui-view> </div>  If i  quoted like this not working.. can u please tell why?

Comment: not without more information about controller and it's scope. read last sentence

Comment: and don't quote `clearance` ...that is a variable and you are turning it into a string